# In JavaScript, how can we use the Microsoft Authentication Library to request a JWT token for a client connection with an an integration user?

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, msal.js

We have a microservice, composed in JavaScript, which needs to consume a second microservice. The second microservice requires the consuming application to provide a JWT token which claims

```
  "roles": [
    "FooBar.Read"
  ],
```

for permission to use the service.

Rather than reinvent the wheel when calling Azure Active Directory to obtain and cache the token, we'd like to make use of the Microsoft Authentication Library node package.

I think we *probably* want to use the `acquireTokenSilent()` method of the `ConfidentialClientApplication`, but I'm not entirely clear how to create the request.

I've created this module:

```
import msal from '@azure/msal-node';
import {cachePlugin} from 'token-cache';


const confidentialClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: {
        authority: `${process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_AUTHORITY_URI}/${process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID}`,
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT_SECRET,
        knownAuthorities: [],
    },
    cache: {
        cachePlugin,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        },
    },
});


const silentFlowRequest = {
    account: {
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID,
        username: process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_PASSWORD,
    },
    scopes: [process.env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_EMPLOYEE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE]
};

async function acquireToken() {
    try {
        return await  confidentialClient.acquireTokenSilent(silentFlowRequest)
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    acquireToken
};
```

However, I expect it to fail because Intell-J tells me:

> Argument type {scopes: string[], account: {password: string, tenantId: string, username: string}} is not assignable to parameter type SilentFlowRequest

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MSAL's client credentials grant using a client secret in order to acquire tokens for your web API. We have a code sample with a fairly explanatory README [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/client-credentials).

The client credentials grant first acquires a token (through `ConfidentialClientApplicaiton.acquireTokenByClientCredentials`) making a network request to AzureAD. Once the token is acquired, it is cached automatically by MSAL and subsequent calls will return the same token from the cache until it expires, at which point MSAL will refresh the token for you.

```js
 // Create msal application object
 const confidentialClientApplication = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    {
      authOptions: {
          clientId: "<ENTER_CLIENT_ID>",
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<ENTER_TENANT_ID>",
          clientSecret: "<ENTER_CLIENT_SECRET>"
        }
    });
  
  // Acquire tokens

function getClientCredentialsToken(confidentialClientApplication, scopes) {
    // With client credentials flows permissions need to be granted in the portal by a tenant administrator. 
    // The scope is always in the format "<resource>/.default"
    const clientCredentialRequest = {
        scopes: scopes
    };

    return confidentialClientApplication
        .acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest)
        .then((response) => {
            // Handle response
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle error
        });
}
```

Essentially, you create a client secret on the Azure Portal and then place it in your MSAL configuration. This secret is used in place of user credentials, allowing your application to authenticate with AzureAD and acquire tokens without any user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for reaching out to us, please follow the doc - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#recommended-pattern-to-acquire-a-token .

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am _hoping_ to figure out how to do this with the MSAL library instead of ADAL as Microsoft's documentation declares "If you choose not to migrate to MSAL before ADAL support ends in December, 2022, you put your app's security at risk. Existing apps that use ADAL will continue to work after the end-of-support date, but Microsoft will no longer release security fixes on ADAL."  ... also, "using a cached token" doesn't sound like the right use case, since the application wouldn't initially have a token in the cache to use.

Comment: Thanks for letting of know, you are using MSAL , please check out the docs for acquiring and access token - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md . if this is not the one you are looking for , could you please elaborate your requirement , so that will try to help you further .

Comment: thank you for your response, but as I tried to communicate in the initial query, I already know I want to use `acquireTokenSilent`, but do not know how to provide a username and password.  The article you liked to does NOT provide that information.

Comment: After calling either loginRedirect or acquireTokenRedirect you'll be redirected to the AAD sign in page and after entering your credentials you'll be redirected back to your app which should now show that a user is signed in , for reference see the doc- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/initialization.md#choosing-an-interaction-type

Comment: This is for an integration user (a.k.a. API user).  There is no human interaction.